# Using QGLFramebufferObject and shaders without QGLWidget

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4

I want to create an OGL data processor using QGLFunctions shaders and framebuffers. I don't need any widgets. But to create valid Shader and framebuffer instances, I need a valid QGLContext with support for the appropriate glExtensions.

With zero context, of course, nothing works. With context of zero QPaintDevice too. With Qpixmap as device it creates a valid context, but it lacks glExtensions for Shader and framebuffer.

```cpp
#include <QGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLFunctions>
// ...
void GLProcessor::init()
{
    auto format = QGLFormat::defaultFormat();

    if (!context()){
        m_context = new QGLContext(format, new QPixmap(1, 1));
        bool ok = m_context->create();
        qDebug() << "CREATING CONTEXT "<< ok;
        Q_ASSERT(context()->isValid());
    }

    context()->makeCurrent();
    initializeGLFunctions(context());
    m_binFBO = new QGLFramebufferObject(lowsize    ,lowsize    ,QGLFramebufferObject::NoAttachment, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RED);
    m_outFBO = new QGLFramebufferObject(lowsize    ,1          ,QGLFramebufferObject::NoAttachment, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RED);
    setupShaders();
    // ...
}
```

There is an option, of course, to do as always is to get the context from the QGLWidget and hide it. But somehow inelegant. PS CUDA, OpenCL, AMP and so on I don't need. For my tasks need OpenGL.

**How do I use shaders and framebuffers in qt4 without creating a QGLWidget?**

Comment: All systems I know require creating a window first in order to connect to the driver and initialize OpenGL, even for off-screen rendering. My guess is that Qt does not abstract it away, so you probably cannot do it without creating a QGLWidget first. Just create a hidden QGLWidget and proceed as usual.

Comment: Why Qt 4? Qt 5 has all the widget-less building blocks that you need.

Comment: My specification requires qt4

Comment: @ybungalobill Qt 5 abstracts (some of that) away. Qt 4 is EOL. Use Qt 5.